# How to create Select2 Multiple value using Bulma in Laravel

Tags: laravel, bulma

I want to create select function on my laravel project , this Select is select2 multiple like on this doc [link](https://select2.org/selections) . on bulma documentation  this select multiple is not have function javascript code . only like this :

```
  <div class="select is-multiple">
  <select multiple size="8">
    <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
    <option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option>
    <option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
    <option value="Chile">Chile</option>
    <option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
    <option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option>
    <option value="Guyana">Guyana</option>
    <option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option>
    <option value="Peru">Peru</option>
    <option value="Suriname">Suriname</option>
    <option value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option>
    <option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

can someone help how to create this select2 so we can add more than 1 value on this field select ?

Comment: use `ctrl + click` that how the `select multiple` works

Comment: its not like on select2  , so we can choose one by one ?

Comment: If you convert your `multiple` select to a select2 select it should just work like in https://jsfiddle.net/k1ejv2h7/. Is it not working?

Comment: wait what . soo i just need a cdn from select 2 ?

Comment: you can see the link. Maybe it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43396252/bulma-css-with-select2-jquery-plugin

Comment: If you're not already including select2 then https://select2.org/getting-started/installation has a few options on how it can be included